# Azure function service bus trigger: How to stop batches of data from event stream and only allow one message from the queue at a time?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-servicebus-queues

This is my first time using Azure functions and service bus.

I'm trying to build a function app in Visual Studio and I am able to connect to the queue topic (which I don't control). The problem is that every time I enable a breakpoint, 10s of messages are processed at once in VS which is making local testing very difficult (not to mention the problems arising from database pools).

How do I ensure that only 1 message gets processed at once until I hit complete?

```
public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("xxx", "yyy", AccessRights.Manage)]BrokeredMessage msg, TraceWriter log)
{
     // do something here for one message at a time.
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem. The best solution so far?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set maxConcurrentCalls to 1 in the host.json. You also could get answer from [host.json reference for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#servicebus)

> maxConcurrentCalls 16  The maximum number of concurrent calls to the callback that the message pump should initiate. By default, the Functions runtime processes multiple messages concurrently. **To direct the runtime to process only a single queue or topic message at a time, set maxConcurrentCalls to 1**

Comment: thank you so much! i cant stress how much this is going to help me debug my solution. god bless

Comment: This answer does not seem valid any more. 'maxConcurrentCalls' is not supported by the schema and the supplied link does not have anything in it regarding 'maxConcurrentCalls'.  Is there an alternative method?

Comment: @SailingJudo The docs now have a link for the SB host.config, which says it's for Azure Functions 2.x.  The maxConcurrentCalls property et al have been moved into  the messageHandlerOptions section.  However, I'm not sure myself that this is working, as we're using maxConcurrentCalls = 1, and via AppInsights I can verify that we have requests being processed in parallel.

Comment: anyone know how to implement this same functionality with storage queues

Comment: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json-v1#sample-hostjson-file) This is for version 1

Answer (score 8):

For function apps 2.0 you need to to update the `host.json` like this:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  ...
  "extensions": {
    "serviceBus": {
      "messageHandlerOptions": {
        "maxConcurrentCalls": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since the `host.json` file is usually published to Azure along with the function itself, it is preferable not to modify it for debugging and development purposes. Any change to host.json can be made to `local.settings.json` instead.

Here is how to set maxConcurrentCalls to 1:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    ...
    "AzureFunctionsJobHost:Extensions:ServiceBus:MessageHandlerOptions:MaxConcurrentCalls": 1
  }
}
```

This override functionality is described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#override-hostjson-values

Comment: Thanks for the answer It should be double underscore __ instead of  : colon so  the setting is "AzureFunctionsJobHost__Extensions__ServiceBus__MessageHandlerOptions__MaxConcurrentCalls": 1,       hope this helps others :-)

Comment: This is a better answer in my opinion, although needs to correct as per @Twisted

Comment: Both colons and underscores work in most circumstances: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51480085/configuring-appsettings-with-asp-net-core-on-azure-web-app-for-containers-whith/51480422#51480422