# Configuring AppSettings with ASP.Net Core on Azure Web App for Containers: Whither Colons?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service

Consider this `appsettings.json`:

```
{
  "Parent": {
    "ChildOne": "C1 from secrets.json",
    "ChildTwo": "C2 from secrets.json"
  }
}
```

According to Microsoft (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2018/06/12/asp-net-core-settings-for-azure-app-service/), if an app using this config was deployed to an AppService in Azure, the config could be overwritten by creating Application settings in Azure in the style `Parent:ChildOne` / `Parent:ChildTwo`.  To be clear: using colons to target a specific piece of config.

This works just fine with a standard AppService:

[image: Colons are fine on an Azure App Service]

However, if you're using Web App for Containers / i.e. a Docker image deployed to an Azure App Service on Linux (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/app-service-linux-intro) you **cannot** use colons:

[image: Colons are not fine on Azure App Service for Linux]

Why?

When you hover over the error you see this message: `This field can only contain letters, numbers (0-9), periods ("."), and underscores ("_")`.  Using `.` does not work alas.

How do you configure say `Parent:ChildOne` in Azure? `Parent.ChildOne` does not work. Can anyone advise?  I can't find any docs on this....

Answer (score 69, accepted):

After more experimentation than I'd like to admit I think I have the answer.

Where you use `:` on an App Service, use a `__` (double underscore) on an App Service with containers.

So `Parent__ChildOne` instead of `Parent:ChildOne`.

To read a little more (not much more), I wrote this up as a blog post here: https://blog.johnnyreilly.com/2018/07/28/azure-app-service-web-app-containers-asp-net-nested-configuration/

Comment: Great, this helped! I'd like to add that for us the Linux part was important. Deploying the same dotnet core (3.1 LTS) API to a Windows App Service Plan can use `Parent:ChildOne` (the portal allows this), but on a Linux App Service Plan it has to be `Parent__ChildOne`.

Comment: how to use special characters for example Test&Test

Comment: @NiranjanGodboleHosmar I don't think you can.  I think the best bet would be to go with standard naming conventions for that (i.e. `TestAndTest`).

Comment: How to use `-`? Does it become `_`?

Comment: Spent some sweet time on Friday evening to find out that, the bicep is able to update settings with : strangely. But failing to do manual or using Powershell scripts. I am using Bicep to add initial settings and then using PowerShell to update one of the value.