# Providing an Azure web app with complex settings configuration

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core

I'm using `appsettings.json` in my ASP.NET Core web application to provide configuration values to my application.  Some of the configuration is more complex than just "name/value pairs", such as the Serilog configuration:

```
"Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "Override": {
            "System": "Warning",
            "Microsoft": "Warning",
            "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information",
            "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication": "Information"
        }
    },
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithThreadId" ],
    "WriteTo": [
        { "Name": "Console" },
        {
            "Name": "File",
            "Args": {
                "path": "C:/Development/logs/log-auth.txt",
                "fileSizeLimitBytes": 1000000,
                "rollOnFileSizeLimit": true,
                "shared": true,
                "flushToDiskInterval": 1,
                "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u3}] {SourceContext} | {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

What I want to know is, how can I provide my Azure web app with this configuration?  I know I could create an `appsettings.Production.json` file and push that when I publish, but what is the point in deploying settings with a publish?  They might as well be hard-coded.  The point of a settings file is that you should be able to change settings and restart the app, changing its behaviour, with no code re-deployment.

The only thing I can see provided by Azure is its "Settings | Configuration" section in the portal, but these settings are only allowed to be simple name/value pairs.  My Serilog configuration is not valid there.  So how can I provide any kind of advanced configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Thiago already said, you can add more then simple key/value configuration using `:`. 
However, if you have to deal with larger application configurations I would suggest using [Azure App Configuration](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-configuration/).

On Linux-hosted web apps, Azure won't allow you to insert colons into configuration settings presumably because it's not allowed in Linux environment variable names.  Instead of colons, use double-underscores (`__`).

See also: [Import or export configuration data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/howto-import-export-data)

Comment: Unfortunately, the Azure app portal doesn't allow colons in the key names.

Comment: hm, pretty sure it does. However, you could try `__` instead - which also works...

Comment: It definitely allows colons in the key names now, perhaps it didn't back in mar 2020.

Comment: @Tone Are you sure that this is also true for Linux based Web Apps? I Know that colons works on Windows

Answer (score 4):

the appsettings.Production.json file is ignored during the publish. You need to use powershell or CI/CD (using Azure Devops for example) in order to define the settings.

About the key/value pairs, you can specify complex types using ':' as the separator For example:

Serilog:MinimumLevel:Default

I've been using the following powershell script:

```
$appname = "name of your function app"
$rg = "name of resource group"
$webApp = Get-AzureRmwebApp -ResourceGroupName $rg -Name $appname
$webAppSettings = $webApp.SiteConfig.AppSettings
$hash = @{}
foreach ($setting in $webAppSettings) {
    $hash[$setting.Name] = $setting.Value
}
$hash['Serilog:MinimumLevel:Default'] = 'Information'
$hash['Serilog:MinimumLevel:Override:System'] = 'Warning'
$hash['Serilog:MinimumLevel:Override:Microsoft'] = 'Warning'
$hash['Serilog:MinimumLevel:Override:Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime'] = 'Information'
$hash['Serilog:MinimumLevel:Override:Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication'] = 'Information'

$hash['Serilog:Enrich:0'] = "FromLogContext"
$hash['Serilog:Enrich:1'] = "WithMachineName"
$hash['Serilog:Enrich:2'] = "WithThreadId"

$hash['Serilog:WriteTo:0:Name'] = "Console"
$hash['Serilog:WriteTo:1:Name'] = "File"
$hash['Serilog:WriteTo:1:Args:path'] = "C:/Development/logs/log-auth.txt"
$hash['Serilog:WriteTo:1:Args:fileSizeLimitBytes'] = "1000000"
$hash['Serilog:WriteTo:1:Args:rollOnFileSizeLimit'] = "true"
$hash['Serilog:WriteTo:1:Args:shared'] = "true"
$hash['Serilog:WriteTo:1:Args:flushToDiskInterval'] = "1"
$hash['Serilog:WriteTo:1:Args:outputTemplate'] = "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u3}] {SourceContext} | {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"


Set-AzureRMWebAppSlot -ResourceGroupName $rg -Name $appname -AppSettings $hash -Slot production
```

PS: double check the settings / values after the execution...

Comment: Unfortunately, the Azure app portal doesn't allow colons in the key names.

Comment: it allows: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cjaliaga/2016/08/10/working-with-azure-app-services-application-settings-and-connection-strings-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: Have you actually tried creating a Web App in Azure app portal and creating config settings through the UI?  That article is from 2016, perhaps they have introduced the restriction since.  Here's a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ey2Ny.png

Comment: In fact I just did. Here's the printscreen: https://postimg.cc/Y4DC3Pdz

Comment: It's working fine for me. Check if there's no empty spaces (before / after). If it's not the case, try using underscore rather than :

Comment: I'm interested as to why it's letting you insert colons.  Could you use LICEcap to show an animated GIF of you creating a new setting through that UI and typing it in?  It's somehow behaving differently for me.

Comment: OK, looking at [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51480085/configuring-appsettings-with-asp-net-core-on-azure-web-app-for-containers-whith) I've figured it out.  It's because the web app is hosted on Linux, which doesn't allow colons (this is why I hate using env variables; they differ per platform!)  On Linux hosts you have to use the double underscore (`__`) instead.

Comment: Thank you for your example. Besides being amazing posh, I didn't know how to present a JSON array in the Azure configuration designer: `Serilog:WriteTo:0:Name`